# How to expand symbolic series

Tags: variables, series, symbolic-math, expand, coefficients

Seeking a solution to expand symbolic series with coefficients and changing variables.

I am trying to expand a symbolic series where coefficients and variables vary. How could I do this?
Consider this example where i varies to number 3.

Sigma[a(i)*x(i)]= a0x0+a1x1+a2x2+a3x3

where i ranges from 0 to 3.

I have not yet found a solution to this. I would like to get an answer using a Python ready function, without using for, while, etc. Please help me. Luciana from Brazil. Thanks!